# In jmeter I got this error " "timestamp":"2022-06-23T17:29:09.277+00:00","status":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"","path" after adding correctpath

Tags: jmeter

"timestamp":"2022-06-23T17:29:09.277+00:00","status":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"","path
this error is got after adding correct path and token

Answer (score 0):

As per [HTTP 403 Forbidden](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403) status code description:

> The HTTP **`403 Forbidden`** response status code indicates that the server understands the request but refuses to authorize it.
>
> This status is similar to [`401`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401), but for the **`403 Forbidden`** status code re-authenticating makes no difference. The access is permanently forbidden and tied to the application logic, such as insufficient rights to a resource.

There is a certain [difference between authentication and authorization](https://www.okta.com/identity-101/authentication-vs-authorization/):

1. Authentication - is whether you can get in or not
2. Authorization - is after getting in what you're allowed to do

So double check that the user you're logging in with is allowed to do what you want to do as it might be the case you're trying to execute an action which the user is not capable of doing (i.e. due to lack of administrator permissions)

You can see all JMeter Variables along with their respective values using [Debug Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script/) and [View Results Tree](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script/) listener combination.